# tensorflow shuffle and batch necessary if building the model sequentially?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am looking at the recurrent neural net walkthrough [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation). In the tutorial they have a line item that does:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

However, if you're doing a sequential build, is that still necessary? Looking at the [sequential](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) documentation, a shuffle is performed automatically? If not, why is it done here? Is there a simple numerical example of the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tf.keras.models.Sequential` can also batch and shuffle the data, similar to what `tf.data.Dataset` does. These preprocessing features are provided in Sequential because it can take up data in several types like NumPy arrays, `tf.data.Dataset`, `dict` object as well as a `tf.keras.utils.Sequence`.

The `tf.data.Dataset` API provides these features because the API is consistent with other TensorFlow APIs ( in which Keras is not involved ).

I don't think the shuffling and batching need to be done twice. You may remove the if you wish, it will not affect the model's training. I think the author wanted to use `tf.data.Dataset` to get the data into a Keras model. `dataset.shuffle( ... ).batch( ... )` have been colloquial with the `Dataset`.

Comment: So, then why is the tf.data.Dataset shuffle? Why not always let the sequential mode handle it?

Comment: As I said, they are colloquial. You will mostly observe the .shuffle and .batch methkd if you are using Dataset